# How to import certificate to keystore on mac os

Tags: java, macos, http, https, keystore

I've downloaded a certificate from a server with cer extension. And tried to import it to keystore with the following command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias https -file MyCrtFile.crt -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

And then I try to find it with command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -alias https
```

But getting an exception

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If the first succeeded and the second failed you must have a typo in the second command.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your JDK directory is correct

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

The command shall work with the default blank password. Getting the "Keystore file does not exist" means the file doesn't exist.

If the keystore exists but the alias doesn't exist, you shall get "Alias  does not exist".